# How to scale a slackbot app

Tags: node.js, scalability, websockets

I'm building an app for slack. While I've completed the POC, and everything works well for a single instance of the app, I'm having an issue of wrapping my mind around the scaling of it.

The specific issue is this:

- the app utilizes the slackbot. A slackbot is a node.js app that opens a websocket to Slack with the relevant credentials
- each installation of the app by the end user will require a slackbot process with the relevant credentials, keys etc.

So, I'll need an app opening a websocket for each installation. Clearly a machine per bot is an overkill. How would i go about running a few instances of the same app on a single machine? What's the best way to make sure that each machine runs the recommended number of bots?

Comment: Cant you put the slackbot in the app? Then every user provides their own machine

Comment: @Ewan I'm not sure what you mean. A slackbot is a nodejs application that connects via a websocket to Slack servers. It needs my database to provide tokens and such. How do I put it on the user's machine?